# Touching a comment owned by a deleted user crashes Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, android-app, deleted-accounts

Steps to reproduce:

1. Find a comment owned by a deleted user, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450/is-mono-ready-for-prime-time/93952#comment220875_93952).
2. Touch it (as you normally would when trying to upvote or flag).
3. Observe as app stops responding.
4. Wait about 8-9 seconds.
5. Observe crash.
6. Look up to the sky, throw your hands in the air, and scream "WHY???!!!" because you really wanted to upvote that comment. ** optional*

Could this be unborkified?

Comment: @Martijn Erm, this one was posted far earlier.

Comment: Yes, I know, but the other post now has an explanation and a `status-completed` tag. You can try and get Geoff to mark this one as completed as well, or we can just close this as a dupe of the other so everyone can see the bug is solved.

Comment: @Tim can also mark this as completed, or remove the status tag altogether as having two different statuses on duplicates is confusing.